# What is the term for the movie theater policy and behavior pre movie clips?

Tags: cinema-history

Just before coming attractions the movie theater houses typically have a set of short movies telling the audience how to behave.

I'm not looking for "Coming Attractions" or "Our feature presentation" videos. The types of videos I'm referring to for ask their customers to not talk, turn off their phones, and don't make a mess.

What is the term for such clips?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions asking about sourcing materials are off topic here. Please see our [help/on-topic] page for more information.

Comment: @Burtyboy80 That's only applicable for movie ID questions, which this clearly is not.

Comment: A common term for these is PSA's or public service announcements.

Comment: I'm reopening this because its been edited to ask what the term is for these kinds of (common) pre-movie announcements.

Comment: Every time I look, it says what @JohnP says, PSA (Public Service Announcement) and are usually also considered "advertisements" by media. Here is a website on PSA https://www.acep.org/ACEP-Taxonomy-of-Subject-Matterews-/All-About-Public-Service-Announcements/#sm.00008fqjof959dz4rwc2mu11h1wyw

Comment: I wonder if these could be considered "[bumpers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bumper_(broadcasting))" in some cases.

Comment: Not sure if this a universal term, but when I worked at a movie theater we called it our "policy trailer"

Answer (score 8):

In my cinema we refer to them as **Etiquette Cues**, and I have heard others refer to them as **Policy Cards** (when it is a written text), but I do not believe the industry has a consistent terminology for them.

More broadly, any additional material in-between adverts/trailers is referred to as an insert, or a message displayed on the screen as the audience enters (which often conveys just such a message) is a **holding slide**.

Comment: Interesting - I know there is quite a bit of difference in terminology between the UK and the states, but we never even hear these terms over here. All materials placed before the start of the feature are either "preshow/ads" or "trailers" depending on what they are. Although it is not customary for theaters here to display anything other than ads or trailers (including policy trailers)

Answer (score 7):

It is called a Policy Trailer. It outlines the theater's policy on smoking, cell phones, fire safety, and of course the concession stand. Large theater chains produce their own trailers. Smaller theaters use one supplied by Coca-cola or Pepsi. Here is a link to a long list of them: http://cinematreasures.org/video/categories/policy-trailers

Answer (score 5):

The general term for these that I am aware of is PSA's or Public Service Announcements.

While [the site referenced](https://www.acep.org/ACEP-Taxonomy-of-Subject-Matterews-/All-About-Public-Service-Announcements/#sm.000007x5fqqm6fe8nrkmsana0q1lk) by @darth locke is not movie specific, it does address the general concept of what a PSA is, and the purpose they serve.

I have also come across the terms "Pre Curtain announcement" or "Pre Show announcement", however these are more related to theater. Given that movies often used to have curtains (And some still do have motorized curtains), it is possible that it could be applied to cinematic applications.

Comment: I'm just going to leave this here for y'all... https://www.youtube.com/user/AlamoDrafthouse